Wordpress Sierra theme "Could not connect to API server"
We have Wordpress site set on Azure web app service with freshly installed Sierra theme by Keydesign. Before license validation we have error:Sierra Api connection and error from server: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: api.keydesign.xyz.
Keydesign support checked the problem and said to contact out host provider(Azure).
In app service's Wordpress settings panel all request from external apis are allowed, nothing is blocking it(in settings).
We wanted to contact Azure support, but it's highly paid per month, so we want to abandon contacting to them.
Does anybody have some idea or had similar problem with Sierra(or other) theme?
I've tryed reinstalling Sierra theme and plugins with disabling plungins maybe causing error. In Azure web app service setting we enabled all foreign requests and disabled some filtering.

OsHiE can you share your code.

Ok, but what code do You need? Some specific file?
